# How to forward the email that is currently open?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro in Excel to reply to the selected email in Outlook with body, send to and cc in the sheet.

Is it possible to change it to reply the email that is currently opened (not selected)? The best option would be to forward the currently opened email to a new recipient.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim emailApplication As Object
    Dim emailItem As Object
    
    Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set emailItem = emailApplication.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).ReplyAll
    
    emailItem.cc = Range("R17")
    
    emailItem.Body = Range("B4")
    
    emailItem.Display
    
    Set emailItem = Nothing
    Set emailApplication = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference the currently opened email inspector

```
ActiveInspector
```

To reference the currently opened email message

```
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

You must have an email message currently opened, otherwise ActiveInspector will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
Set emailItem = emailApplication.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).ReplyAll
```

with

```
Set emailItem = emailApplication.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.ReplyAll
```

You would need to add a couple of sanity checks (`emailApplication.ActiveInspecto`r is not null and `emailApplication.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` is `MailItem`, (check that `Class = olMailItem`))